# Laravel 5.1 - DB transaction exception not thrown after fatal error

Tags: laravel, transactions

I have a db transaction with an event inside it like this:

```
    DB::beginTransaction();

    try {
        event(new sendMessage($message, $to, $from));
    }
    catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        return 'error';
    }

    DB::commit();
```

This event has 2 working listeners setup; the issue is that if there is an error (if something went wrong) in one of the listeners, like an incorrect variable name, the transaction's catch exception 'error' is never returned, only the actual error gets logged, but 'error' isn't returned from the transaction.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it so that if any of the listeners fail for any reason the exception of the transaction is thrown?

**EDIT:**

So it looks like if the mistake is in the listeners the exception is thrown correctly. The issue seems to be if the event constructor itself has an error:

```
public function __construct(Message $message, $to, $from)
{
    $this->messege = $message; //notice the incorrect messege spelling
    $this->to = $to;
    $this->from = $from;
}
```

I was expecting the exception to be thrown from the db transaction, but instead this gets logged:

```
[2015-07-29] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to a member function message() on null' in */Listeners/Messages/CreateMessage.php:38
```

Where CreateMessage.php is a listener that uses the variable $message.

```
class CreateMessage {
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle(sendMessage $event)
    {
        $event->message->message()->create([  // Exception above get thrown because of the 'messege' typo in the event
            'to'      => $event->to,
            'from'    => $event->from
        ]);
    }
}
```

So the final question is if a case like this exists, with a typo in a variable name that an event listener uses, how can I return the db transaction error?

Comment: at first your transactions should be inside sendMessage constructor

Comment: @M0rtiis I have the above transaction in the MessageController, so I should leave it there, and I have 3 other files. sendMessage event, sendMessageListener1, sendMessageListener2. I am not sure what you mean by the transaction should be inside the constructor of the sendMessage event. Can you show an example/pseudocode?

Comment: im speaking about that its better way to put this `DB::beginTransaction(); ... DB::commit();` around the actual queries. But im not seeng queries in your example. about constructor is said because (looking to your example) they might be somwhere inside `new sendMessage($message, $to, $from)`. sorry if i confused u

Comment: @M0rtiis there are 2 queries. One inside sendMessageListener1, and another inside sendMessageListener2. I am trying so that if there is any error in either of those listeners, which are fired by the sendMessage event that I put in the transaction, it will fail the transaction itself and return the transaction 'error'

Comment: u should certainly show us your listeners

Comment: @M0rtiis I updated the question with an edit that is the exact issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. U can not catch FATAL errors. There is no way for it with continuing script execution.
Because after they appear script no longer executes.
So u can understand it as:

After this string

```
$event->message->create(
```

Your code "not exists".
And your `catch(\Exception $e)` "not exists" too.
See 1 16 64 4096 rows description here http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

The only way to do SOMETHING (but not want u want) after fatal error appears is to use [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)

And laravel desided last thing to do is to throw you this exeption

```
'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to a member function message() on null' in */Listeners/Messages/CreateMessage.php:38
```

But you cant catch it, script stops after that.
Thats it.

Lets see what we have about it in Laravel-core:

**vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php**

```
public function bootstrap(Application $app)
{
    $this->app = $app;

    error_reporting(-1);

    set_error_handler([$this, 'handleError']);

    set_exception_handler([$this, 'handleException']);

    register_shutdown_function([$this, 'handleShutdown']);

    if (!$app->environment('testing')) {
        ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
    }
}
```

we are interested in  `register_shutdown_function([$this, 'handleShutdown']);` :

```
/**
 * Handle the PHP shutdown event.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handleShutdown()
{
    if (!is_null($error = error_get_last()) && $this->isFatal($error['type'])) {
        $this->handleException($this->fatalExceptionFromError($error, 0));
    }
}
```

here we interested in `$this->fatalExceptionFromError($error, 0)`:

```
/**
 * Create a new fatal exception instance from an error array.
 *
 * @param  array  $error
 * @param  int|null  $traceOffset
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
 */
protected function fatalExceptionFromError(array $error, $traceOffset = null)
{
    return new FatalErrorException(
        $error['message'], $error['type'], 0, $error['file'], $error['line'], $traceOffset
    );
}
```

look at this:

```
* @return \Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
```

they throw exactly the same exeption that you recieved

Comment: So if there is no possible way for me to return the DB catch exception 'error' what would I do to return the 'error' to the front end, instead of it only being logged and not returned?

Comment: u should write without typo-errors, or change programming language to different than PHP. u can do NOTHING  with that

Comment: the only way in laravel to do somthing with it is http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#terminable-middleware

Comment: still not 100% sure how to implement it to return the 'error' response